# Why won't my Canvas show up?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150">
  <p>Désolé, votre navigateur ne supporte pas Canvas mettez le donc à jour</p>
</canvas>
<script>
  var canvas  = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var test = new Image();
  test.src = 'test.jpg'; // I'm sure that test.jpg is in the folder
  context.drawImage(test, 35, 35);
</script>
```

Can you please help me? My canvas does exist but I can't insert an image in it. Why? Can someone explain me?

Comment: Désolé, votre navigateur ne supporte pas Canvas mettez le donc à jour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the image has downloaded, by using its `load` event.

```
var test = new Image();

test.onload = function() { context.drawImage(test, 35, 35); };

test.src = 'test.jpg';
```